# How do I reference other beans from within a configuration class in spring?

Tags: java, spring, swing, configuration

I have various swing actions in a swing/spring application.  They are annotated as @Component so they should be visible after component autoscanning.  I have a configuration class where I am defining a bean for a menu for the main frame/window.  The method to create/return the menu object has to reference the actions as necessary.  In a Beans.xml setting, I would just do something like:

```
<bean id="mainMenu" class="javax.swing.JMenu">
     <constructor-arg id="0" value="Schedule" />
     <constructor-arg id="1">
          <value type="int">0</value>
     </constructor>
</bean>
```

Then, in the setter for the bean in the main form, I would autowire before the setter and add the items.  In swing there's no way to as a property set the menu items - you have to add them.  In a beans.xml setting, I can though reference a bean by id or type in another bean's creation.  How do I do that in my configuration class?  Like this is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.draconia.ngucc.usher")
public class BeanConfiguration
{
    private Action mActCreateSchedule, mActEditSchedule, mActExit, mActRemoveSchedule;
    private JMenu mMnuSchedule;

    @Bean("scheduleMenu")
    public JMenu getScheduleMenu()
    {
        if(mMnuSchedule == null)
            {
            mMnuSchedule = new JMenu("Schedule");
            mMnuSchedule.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

            mMnuSchedule.add(getCreateScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.add(getEditScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.add(getRemoveScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.addSeparator();
            mMnuSchedule.add(getExitAction());
            }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to instead of the get functions, or maybe have get functions to access the items - in the get functions then there would be something like return((CreateSchedule)(getBean(CreateSchedule.class))) (I think I have enough/right number of parentheses there haha).  I'd just need access to an application context.  Can I somehow autowire one(an application context) in the configuration class or how would I possibly get access to a getBean to access those component scanned beans?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`@Autowired` ApplicationContext into the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.draconia.ngucc.usher")
public class BeanConfiguration
{
    private Action mActCreateSchedule, mActEditSchedule, mActExit, mActRemoveSchedule;
    private JMenu mMnuSchedule;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Bean("scheduleMenu")
    public JMenu getScheduleMenu()
    {
        if(mMnuSchedule == null)
            {
            mMnuSchedule = new JMenu("Schedule");
            mMnuSchedule.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

            mMnuSchedule.add(getCreateScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.add(getEditScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.add(getRemoveScheduleAction());
            mMnuSchedule.addSeparator();
            mMnuSchedule.add(getExitAction());
            }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to make use of ApplicationContextAware interface like :

```
@Component
public class ContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        ContextUtil.context=context;

    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public static void setContext(ApplicationContext context) {
        ContextUtil.context = context;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String beanName){

        return getContext().getBean(beanName);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll give those suggestions a shot - Thank you!